# Robot Framework: is it possible to ignore error "Initializing test library 'abc' with arguments [ abc ] failed"?

Tags: robotframework

I'm setting up a Library in Settings like this:

```
Library    abc    ${SYSTEM}    WITH NAME    pvm
```

but I need to add one more argument `${host}` and I can't remove the first import, just need to reinitiniliaze the Library like that:

```
Library    abc    ${SYSTEM}    ${host}    WITH NAME    pvm
```

Everything is working but an error appears in log.html:

`"Error in file '/keywords.robot': Initializing test library 'abc' with arguments [ abc ] failed: "`

because it cannot find ${SYSTEM} since the argument ${host} is missing.

Is it possible to ignore the error and proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the library within the test setup or test case. See [Import Library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Import%20Library)